# Unstable solution for simple harmonic motion using dormand-prince and RK4 method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the differential equation for a simple harmonic motion in javascript that is given by

$$
mx'' = -kx
$$

We know the solution is a sinusoidal. The problem I face is that the amplitude of the sinusoidals in my solution are increasing exponentially.

So the first method I tried was using the numeric.js, It uses the doramnd-prince method to solve the equation. The relevant code the library uses to solve this ODE is https://github.com/sloisel/numeric/blob/master/src/numeric.js#L2885-L2999

Next I tried this GMA1D library, I think it uses RK4 method. There relevant function that the library use to solve the ODE is here https://github.com/llarsen71/GMA1D/blob/gh-pages/javascripts/ODE.js#L89-L123

Here is my implementation

```
simulate(){
    var state = [this.x, this.dx]
    var time = this.T;

    //var F = 2*Math.sin((-2) - state[0])
    var F = -5*state[0];

    console.log(`Position x : ${this.x}, Velocity v : ${this.dx} at time t: ${this.T}`);
    // calculate new position one one is used the other is commented out

    // Method 1 - Dormand prince
    [this.x, this.dx ]= numeric.dopri(0,0.02,state,function(t,x){return [x[1], F]}).at(0.02);
    // Method 1 - END

    /// Method 2 RK4
    var V = function(t,pt){
      var x = pt[0], y =pt[1];
      return [y, F]
    }
    var ode_ = new ODE(V);
    var soln = ode_.solve(1,0.02,this.T,state);
    this.x = soln.pts[1][0]
    this.dx = soln.pts[1][1]
    // Method 2 - END

    this.T += 0.02;

  }
```

For both these libraries my solution becomes unstable as I iterate, I have tried to change the step size but that does not help. I have the following questions

1. I dont't have much experience with MATLAB ode45, but I would likely get a correct solution from MATLAB. What method does it use to solve the DE, if its dormand-prince why does numeric.js solution is unstable, are there different variationso of dormand-prince. If yes, which one should I use?
2. Can someone provide code for solving the above DE in MATLAB and plotting the result?
3. Can I expect a correct solution from RK4?
4. Which method should I use to solve Differential Equations?
5. While trying to figure out the problem I read about stiff and non-stiff equations, what are these types of equations and how that analysis is useful?
6. Point me to some good resources where I can learn more about all the above questions so next time I have a better understanding. :)
7. Does anyone know any good Javascript libraries to solve differential equations?

Gracias

Comment: What did you use for $m$, $k$ and the initial conditions as I don't want to look through that code - can you add those to the problem statement?

Comment: I used m =1 and k = 5, will they affect if the solution is unstable or not?

Comment: Also the initial conditions are x(0)= -1 and x'(0) = 0

Comment: The solution to this ODE is not stable: think of it as a rock on the top of a hill, it seems stable but a little variation makes it crumble. So your numeric solution can easily accumulate rounding errors. According to how much time you have to simulate I'd add a little damping.

Comment: I see, can I get a correct result using MATLAB's ode45, and how can I figure out which ODEs are not stable?

Comment: You can have the analytical solution $x=A\cos \left ( \sqrt {k \over m} t \right ) + B\sin \left ( \sqrt {k \over m} t \right )$. You can find A and B from $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$. About the stability there it is a full field of control theory, without knowing what you want to simulate (and without a prior knowledge of at least matrix analysis) it is very hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Anyway, looking at your code, I'd replace F in your functionals to integrate with the evaluation: -5 * x[0] or -5 * pt[0]

Comment: @N74 I am aware of the analytical solution but I would like to solve it using numerical analysis method. By stability I meant, the stability of the numerical solution method per se and not the system itself, the system we know is marginally stable(Oh now it makes a little more sense "rock on a the top of a hill"). I have studied control systems and linear algebra so please be as descriptive as you can or need to be. Thanks :)

Comment: THANKS @N74. Replacing F by -5* x[0] helps. The solution value is still increasing but its very slow compared to what it was before. I had almost lost my faith in numerical analysis methods :) I thought the method was using a single step to calculate the solution at t=t+0.02 I need to study numerical analysis in much more detail.

Comment: All higher order numeric methods (than Euler) evaluate the function at more than one point, that's why you need to pass a functional and not a constant value. Anyway I'm happy it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a javascript question.

The problem is that you return a global variable in the vector field instead of the function of the state passed as argument. Define the force `F` as proper function of a state vector argument,

```
var F = function(x) { return -5*x[0]; }
```

and use that in the ODE system functions,

```
[this.x, this.dx ]= numeric.dopri(0,0.02,state,function(t,x){return [x[1], F(x)]}).at(0.02);
```

and

```
var V = function(t,pt){
  var x = pt[0], y =pt[1];
  return [y, F(pt)]
}
```

Then the methods should have the corrects slopes at their interior stages and thus the correct error order which should then give a similar error order to the amplitude.

Comment: Still this doesn't account for the marginal stability of the problem, as the OP observed in the next to last comment to the question.

Comment: The code as it is ignores the Dopri results, overwrites them directly with the RK4 results. $0.02$ is a sensible step size for this problem and RK4, but far from the optimal $0.0005$. At time somewhere between $t=6$ to $t=8$ the step error will be magnified into visibility, giving an increasing phase and amplitude error.